# Adding collision detection to images on HTML5 canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, draggable

I have the following JavaScript function, which I'm using to try and enable images to be dragged and dropped around a HTML5 canvas:

```
function canvasState(myGameCanvas){

var bounding_box = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
//var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-bounding_box.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/bouding_box.width);
//var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (myGameCanvas.height/bounding_box.height);
//var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);

this.valid = false; /*When set to true, the canvas will redraw everything */
this.allImagesArray; /*This is the array holding all of the images to be drawn */
this.dragging = false; /*Keep track of when the current selected object is being dragged */
this.selection = null;
this.dragOffX = 0; /*See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation */
this.dragOffY = 0;

this.interval = 30; /*This variable will be used to determine how often the draw method is called. */

/*Save a reference to the canvasState so that I'm still using this particular canvasState. */
var myState = this;

/*This stops double clicking on the canvas selecting text on the canvas */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
console.log("Event Listener 'selectstart' added to canvas.");
/*Up, down and move are for dragging */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    console.log("Event Listener 'mousedown' added to canvas");
    //var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    var mX = e.clientX;
    var mY = e.clientY;
    console.log("ClientX = " + mX + "clientY = " +mY);
    var allImages = myState.allImagesArray;
    var NoOfImages = allImages.length;
    for (var i = 1-1; i >= 0; i--){
        /*At the moment this is looking for coordinates in the array. It should
            be looking for images at that position. I want to get coordinates for 
            all images in the array, and calculate whether the click is on one of those.*/
        if(allImages[i].contains(mX, mY)){
            var mySelection = allImages[i];
            /*Keep track of where in the object was clicked, so that it can be 
                moved smoothly (see mousemove) */
                alert("test");
            myState.dragOffX = mX - mySelection.x;
            myState.dragOffY = mY - mySelection.y;
            myState.dragging = true;
            myState.selection = mySelection;
            myState.valid = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    /*If the code hasn't returned, it means that nothing has been selected.
    If there was an object selected, then deselect it. */
    if (myState.selection){
        myState.selection = null;
        myState.valid = false; /*Need to clear the old selection border */

    }
}, true);

/*This event checks to see if the dragging flag has been set to true. If it has, it gets the
current mouse position and moves the selected object to that position, remembering the offset
where it was selected. If the dragging flag is false, the event does nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    console.log("Event listener 'mousemove' added to canvas.");
    if(myState.dragging){
        var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
        /*I don't want to drag the object by its top left corner, I want to drag from where the
        object was clicked. That's why I saved the offset and use it here. */
        myState.selection.x = e.clientX - myState.dragOffX;
        myState.selection.y = e.clientY - myState.dragOffY;
        myState.valid = false; /*Something's dragging, so I must redraw */
    }
}, true);

/*All the mouseup event has to do is update the canvas state so that it is no longer dragging.
So, once the mouse button is lifted, the mousemove event should be back to doing nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    console.log("Event listener 'mouseup' added to canvas.");
    myState.dragging = false;
}, true);

//setInterval(function(){ myState.draw(); }, myState.interval);

canvasState.prototype.draw = function(){
    /*If the state is invalid,redraw and validate. */
    if (!this.valid){
        var context = this.context;
        var images = this.images;
        this.clear();

        /*Redraw the game elements here */
        drawLevelOneElements();
    }
}


}
```

However, for some reason, when I view my web page in a browser, although all of the images are displayed on the canvas, and a console log displays the position of the cursor on the canvas when you click, for some reason the line

```
selectedImage.draggable = "true";
```

doesn't seem to have made any of the images draggable. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit 06-12-2012 @ 10:40 to show changed code**

All of the images are still being displayed on the canvas when the start button is clicked- I have a printout in the console starting at 0, and incrementing by one each time an image is drawn to the canvas from the array.

Once all of the images have been drawn to the canvas (and the printout has reached 33- as there are 34 images in the array), I then get the line "Event listener 'mousemove' added to the canvas" being printed out to the console several times (maybe about 30). If I click on the canvas again, that loop is called again, printing that line another 30 or so times. None of the images are draggable either. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to take a look at kineticjs. It does a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: Are you sure that line is even executed... put an "alert('test');" to be sure the if statement becomes true when you click on an image.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest... I've changed the code a bit now since posting this, and I'm getting a long list of "Event listener 'mousemove' added to canvas" printouts in the console... I'll edit my original post to include the code that I now have.

Comment: Collisions can be maybe checked from a heap if all your objects on the canvas are created at node objects.